# Elegant way of organizing a lookup status table

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic

I have an application that receives numerous items a day that require two employee reviews. Once an item is received and entered into the database it then goes into the review process.

The review process goes something like this.

- Receive item and mark apply label "first checker"

  - The first checker is able to put the item in one of two pending states or clear it. Clearing the item automatically replaces the item label to "second checker?"
  - If an item enters a pending state it stays there until a reviewer makes a final decision.
- The second checker checks the item an picks a final decision.
- The item is marked as complete.

I currently have a table in my database called `Statuses` with the following columns.

```
Id
Name
```

And the data in this table (in `Id`, `Name` format).

```
0, First Checker
1, Second Checker
2, Pending State A
3, Pending State B
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the code has no way or knowing that once the first checker completes their check and doesn't put the item in a pending state that the next label the item should get is `1, Second Checker`. The only way I can figure out to overcome this is by adding a series of columns to this table. For example, I currently have `IsFirstChecker`, `IsSecondChecker` and `IsPendingStatus` columns.

So with all of these extra columns I'm able to check when an item review is saved, if a final decision was made then query the database for the status where `IsSecondChecker` is `true` to change the label (or status, if you will) with the `Id` (FK of the `Items` table) retrieved.

It doesn't seem like a very ideal solution but it works. Is there a better way of solving this?

I wanted to add that this solution does work with very little code logic. I started thinking about it some more and thought maybe there was another way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a finite state machine!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Might be overkill for the current requirement - but it's an elegant, extensible way of modeling the "what happens next" question.